# How to change placeholder for an textarea?

Tags: jquery, forms, textarea, placeholder, attr

This code submits a form and it works, except changing placeholder for textarea `id=message`

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
   $.post("mail.php", $("#contact").serialize(), function(response) {
   $('#message').attr('placeholder', response);
   $('#success').html(response);
   });
});
```

There is no error in Firebug.

Comment: Are you clearing the value of the textarea? Placeholder text won't show if the element has a value or entered text.

Comment: @vyx.ca, how can I clear  the textarea, pls

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$('#message').prop('placeholder', response);
```

Read [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Comment: Tushar, it seems it doesn't work. I tried ` $('#message').text('');` to clear the textarea before - without result.

Comment: @SunSky alert out `response` what you get ?

Answer (score 4):

Use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$('#message').prop('placeholder', response);
```